# Why did Inosuke called Tanjiro as "Kentaro"?

Tags: demon-slayer

I know it's not important to ask this question but then I'm only curious about this. Who is "Kentaro"?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inosuke has trouble remembering names of people. This was just after he met Tanjiro, so he didn't get his name right. Another instance was when they first met after Tanjiro defeated the ex-Lower Moon Kyogai, Inosuke called him **Kamaboko Gonpachiro.** [Here's the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KY2X94bZofI&t=3s)

PS: He can get names just right after he'd met someone for a few times

Comment: Thanks, I thought it has some reason or meaning about Tanjiro that's why he called him some random names. Now I know it's all about him.